# open text file with imacros on firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I'm using XMLHttpRequest from years ago on firefox up to v39 to read local text file but the firefox disable XHR in all the new version of firefox from 40 until now I want to update my source code of javascript to get it working with the new version of firefox

Here is my old code :

```
    function readTextFile(file)
    {const XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1");
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {         allText = rawFile.responseText;
                      }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
        rawFile = null;
        }
readTextFile("file:///D:/textfile.txt");
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate the issue. Just try like so:

```
const xhr = new Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1")();
xhr.open("GET", "file:///D:/textfile.txt", false);
xhr.send(null);
var text = xhr.response;
// alert(text);
```

Comment: your sourcode is very simple but the firefox removed xhr at all and replace with fitcher api
can you update the script with the new API

Comment: I don't think so about XHR. Tested successfully on Firefox 47 and 'iMacros for Firefox' 8.9.7. If you mean [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), it doesn't seem to be useful in this case.